# Criar diretiva para máscara

Tags: angularjs

Quero usar a máscara `xx/xx/xxxx` em um campo de data e retornar no objeto com a máscara, não somente o valor. Usei uma diretiva `ui-mask`, porém não retorna com a máscara, já usei o `model-view-value="true"` mas não funciona, então quero criar uma diretiva que apenas pegue o valor e adicione as barras "//" via `javascript` com `substring`, somente isso. Mas como fica para utilizar junto com `ui-mask`? pela lógica, a diretiva teria que ser executada após a data ser toda digitada?

Segue o que eu fiz:

```
angular.module("modulo").directive("uiDate", function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var _formatDate = function (date) {
                date = date.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
                if(date.length > 2) {
                    date = date.substring(0,2) + "/" + date.substring(2);
                }
                if(date.length > 5) {
                    date = date.substring(0,5) + "/" + date.substring(5,9);
                }
                return date;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Porém ainda não funciona, pois a execução dela não está chamando de acordo, é chamada somente ao carregar a página, teria que ser após o campo já ter a data, para retornar apenas para meu ng-model o valor com a máscara. Como ficaria?

Comment: você precisa usar a diretiva ou teria problema usar um plugin externo? Se não tiver problema, dê uma olhada nesse: https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask é bem completo e funciona legal

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a funcão `$watch` dentro da função link, onde a mesmo vai observar as mudanças que ocorrem na propriedade, e então você pode aplicar a lógica de máscara no valor de datas.

```
scope.$watch('propriedade', function (valorAtual, valorAnterior) {
    //código.
});
```

[Documentação para $watch (inglês)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: Utilizar para que? Onde? Como? Quando?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer com que a função seja executada sempre que o usuário digitar, ou, colocar um `timeout` para executar sempre `n` segundos após ele ter parado de digitar.

Qual utilizar então?

Se você deseja que o usuário veja a alteração em tempo real, utilize **sem** o `timeout`. Mas se não tem problema o usuário digitar tudo e só depois formatar a data, pode usar com `timeout`. Ou como você achar melhor.

Para isso, basta usar o método `element.onkeypress = function()...`, veja:

```
return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

        element.onkeypress = function() { //É aqui que ele executa a função sempre que uma tecla for pressionada
            var _formatDate = function (date) {
                date = date.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
                if(date.length > 2) {
                    date = date.substring(0,2) + "/" + date.substring(2);
                }
                if(date.length > 5) {
                    date = date.substring(0,5) + "/" + date.substring(5,9);
                }
                return date;
            };
        } //finaliza o element.onkeypress

    }
};
```

Ou, se você for utilizar com `timeout`, utilize da seguinte maneira:

```
element.onkeypress = function() {
    $timeout(function(){
        var _formatDate = function(date) {
        //... restante do código aqui
    }, 1000);
}
```

Por que estou dando essa resposta e no que ela difere da resposta anterior, que utiliza o `$watch`?

Há muita controvérsia no uso da propriedade `$watch` quando nos referimos a performance, já que ela está associada ao disparo do `$digest`, que é o ciclo que atualiza todas as variáveis de `$scope` de sua página. Então, quanto mais variáveis você possuir, mais pesado sua aplicação ficará com o uso de `$watch`, já que ele precisará analisar todas as variáveis sempre que o campo sofrer alteração de valor.

O método `onkeypress` não passa por isso, pois ele independe dos valores de variáveis, ele depende apenas da interação com o campo.

Comment: a função é chamada corretamente, porem não retorna o valor para o ngModel.

Comment: depurando vi que a data fica como quero, porem não ta setando no ngModel

Comment: Tente adicionar `scope:true` antes de iniciar o `link`

Comment: continua retornando sem as barras, porem depurando o return ja ta a data correta, mas não fica no ngmodel

Comment: vou fazer uns testes aqui e daqui a pouco retorno.

Comment: ok, fico no aguardo...

Answer (score 0):

funcionou de boa pra mim assim:

```
angular.module("aeronaves").directive("uiDate", function() {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
            var _formatDate = function(date){
                date = date.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
                if(date.length > 2) {
                    date = date.substring(0,2) + "/" + date.substring(2);
                }
                if(date.length > 5){
                    date = date.substring(0,5) + "/" + date.substring(5,9);
                }

                return date;
            };

            element.bind("keyup", function (){
                ctrl.$setViewValue(_formatDate(ctrl.$viewValue));
                ctrl.$render();
            });
        }
    };
```

});